# UIScrollView + Autolayout issue

Tags: uiscrollview, constraints, autolayout

Considering the following structure:

| UIScrollView  | UITextField |      (UIScrollView on the left and a UITextField the right)

I am trying to add a UILabel into the UIScrollView and make the UIScrollView grow according to the UILabel size. The UITextFiled would then get smaller according to the grow of the UIScrollView.

```
- (IBAction)makeScrollViewGrow:(id)sender
    self.myScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    myLabel.text = @"THIS IS A LONG MESSAGE";
    myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
    UITextField *theTextField = self.myTextField;
    [self.myTextField removeConstraint:self.titleTextFieldWidthConstraint];
    [self.myScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myLabel]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myLabel)]];
    [self.myScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[myLabel]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myLabel)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[theSCrollView]-8-[theTextField]-20-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(theSCrollView, theTextField)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[theSCrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(theSCrollView)]];
}
```

The issue here is that the UIScrollView is not being resized because the UITextField has a fixed width. If I remove programatically the width UITextField constraint the UIScrollView takes over the all width without considering the text Label (intrinsicContentSize).
Will I need to set the Scrollview contentsize manually or can I do this automatically using autolayout?

Thanks